# How to play sound only when marker is detected in Unity Vuforia

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, audio, vuforia

I am implementing an AR Android app in Unity using Vuforia. I am trying to play a sound as soon as the marker is detected and then stop the sound as the marker is not detected. When I currently build and run the app on the phone the sound is playing directly without me having to track the target which is not what I want.

This is my code in C#:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class Sound : DefaultTrackableEventHandler
{

    protected override void OnTrackingFound()
    {

        base.OnTrackingFound();
        AudioSource[] sounds = GetComponentsInChildren<AudioSource>();

        sounds[0].Play();
    }

    protected override void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        base.OnTrackingLost();

        AudioSource[] sounds = GetComponentsInChildren<AudioSource>();

        sounds[0].Stop();


    }

}
```

Does someone know why this code snippet is not working? And if so, what might I be missing?

Thanks.

Comment: can you share the console log?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge I think, You have to give it in the update function, whether the tracking is found or not. If the tracking is found, sound plays.